# convergence if functional is linear but not bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Assume we have a sequence $X_{n}$ taking values in $\ell_{1}$ space and assume that $g:\ell_{1} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear not bounded functional. Also assume that
$$
X_{n} \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} a
$$
and $||X_{n}|| < c$ for all $n$.

Is the following true?

$$
g(X_{n}) \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} g(a)?
$$

The try: I am trying to use the fact that the bounded linear functional is continuous iff it is bounded. In our case the sequence is bounded and I feel it gives us the same to make the conjecture true.

Edit: what if $g(X_{n}) = \sum_{i} X_{n,i}$? This function is not bounded. Isn't sum function continuous $\ell_{1} \to \ell_{1}$?

Wouldn't then we have $\sum_{i}X_{n,i} \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} \sum_{i}a_{i}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not even true with norm convergence. That's precisely what "not continuous" means!

It seems to me that you are confusing what "bounded" means for an operator. An  unbounded functional will map certain bounded sequences to unbounded sets.

Consider this example: let
$$
c_{00}=\{x\in\ell^1:\ \text{ there exists } n_0\ \text{ such that } x(n)=0,\ n\geq n_0\}. 
$$
Define $g:c_{00}\to\mathbb R$ by
$$
g(x)=(x_1,2x_2,3x_3,\ldots)
$$
Then $g$ is not bounded, for $g(e_n)=n$, where $e_n$ is the sequence with $1$ in the $n^{\rm th}$ position and zeroes elsewhere, and $\|e_n\|=1$. More concretely, we can construct a sequence $z_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}\,e_n$. Then $\|z_n\|=\frac1{\sqrt n}$, so $z_n\to0$ in norm, while $g(z_n)=\sqrt n$.

Our $g$ is only defined on a dense subset of $\ell^1$, but any linear map on a subspace can be extended to a linear map on the whole space. Such extensio $g$ will still satisfy the above examples.

---

After checking, I see that in $\ell^1$ almost sure convergence is pointwise convergence. It is not enough for a linear functional to be bounded for it to be continuous under almost sure convergence. An easy example is $g(x)=\sum_kx_k$, and the sequence $\{e_n\}$ mentioned above. Then $e_n\to0$ pointwise (so almost surely in this context) but $g(e_n)=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I am confused with "not continous". Assume that $g$ is the sum function, as I updated in the question. Then wouldn't we have, for example, $\sum_{i}X_{n,i} \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} \sum_{i}a_{i}$?

Comment: The sum function is trivially bounded in $\ell^1$. You have 
$$
|g(x)|=\Big|\sum_k x_k\Big|\leq\sum_k|x_k|=\|x\|_1.
$$
It's a bounded map with $\|g\|=1$. I don't know what almost sure convergence is in this context, so I cannot comment on whether it converges under $g$.

Comment: I have checked to refresh what almost sure convergence means in this case, and it turns out that for $\ell^1$ it is just pointwise convergence. This is a weaker notion than norm convergence, so continuity is harder. I added an example in the answer of a bounded linear functional that is not continuous under pointwise convergence.